# SQL Server: how to pause a scheduled job between two times?

Tags: sql-server, scheduler, jobs

Is there a way to pause a scheduled job in SQL Server to **NOT** run between two times a day?

I have a recurring job that starts every 2 hours, daily from 12am. However, I want the job to not run between 4pm and 6pm. So I want it to run as follows:

12am, 2am, 4am, 6am, 8am, 10am, 12pm, 2pm, 8pm, 10pm and back to midnight.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Simple solution: Within the job (at its beginning), test the hour and, if within the NO RUN window, simply terminate it.

Comment: @FDavidov - care to share that as an answer with an example please? Besides, I don't want to terminate the job. I want to pause it

Comment: you can also use the WAITFOR clause within your job steps

Comment: [Here I assume that your job has a single step; if not, you may need to repeat the same thing in all steps] You don't really need me to give you the code. Simple add at the beginning of the step a check like `IF(HOUR(GETDATE() IN (16,18))) RETURN ;`. Also, note that you are NOT stopping the job but stopping an EXECUTION INSTANCE of the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to split your job in two schedules
(12am to 4pm and 6pm to 10pm).
You can handle this by implementing your own scheduling with a data model and some stored procedures.
Hope it helps.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Thanks. I did that, but it's not "ideal".